# How to set a thumbnail for a playlist with youtube api in php?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to set a thumbnail for a playlist at the time of its creation, I'm doing this :

```
// 1. Create the snippet for the playlist. Set its title and description.
$playlistSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistSnippet();
$playlistSnippet->setTitle('Test Playlist  ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$playlistSnippet->setDescription('A private playlist created with the YouTube API v3');
$playlistSnippet->setThumbnails ('https://www.google.co.ve/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidvaDtwbPTAhVhKpoKHWf5CboQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimagenesbonitas.bosquedefantasias.com%2F&psig=AFQjCNHfcV6nKOO6oU7iwv3LCfb6GBFkAg&ust=1492794187290336');
```

but the problem is that the thumbnails in the playlist is :

```
"thumbnails": {
    (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
    }
```

So I don't know how to create an object of that way and then add it to the snippet object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full prototype of `setThumbnails` is :

```
setThumbnails(Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails $thumbnails)
```

`Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails` has the following methods :

```
setDefault( Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail $default )
setHigh( Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail $high )
setMaxres( Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail $maxres )
setMedium( Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail $medium )
setStandard( Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail $standard )
```

`Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail`'s methods :

```
setHeight( mixed $height )
setUrl( mixed $url )
setWidth( mixed $width )
```

The following would work to set the thumbnails :

```
$thumbnailDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails();
$thumbnail = new Google_Service_YouTube_Thumbnail();
$thumbnail->setUrl("https://example.com/image.jpg");
$thumbnail->setHeight(720);
$thumbnail->setWidth(1280);

thumbnailDetails->setDefault($thumbnail);

$playlistSnippet->setThumbnails($thumbnailDetails);
```

Comment: Do you know if I can use a blob image for the url of the image?

Comment: You mean to put your blob data in the `url` field ? I don't think this would work as it expects a valid url but you can try

Comment: Does not work with blob format. Btw, $playlistSnippet->setThumbnails(thumbnailDetails); -> You forgot the symbol '$'. But Thank you so much, this works for me. Is there a page where you can consult these functions?

Comment: I've found [this php doc](https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Service_YouTube_ThumbnailDetails.html) which is not official but link back to the official source code.